# Howto dedicate one cpu core to os in PostgreSQL DB server

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

we have dedicated PostgreSQL(9.0.4) sever (ubuntu 10.04.2LTS) with 2CPUs (8 cores total). On some queries postgres processes eat up all CPU's and we are unable to ssh to our server. I wonder if is where any possibility to dedicate one core for OS/system use?

Comment: Are you sure? A single database connection (a.k.a. single database proces), can only use a single core. That means that no query will ever be able to eat up all CPU's/cores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to change the Postgres' process affinity.

First you'll need schedutils:

```
apt-get install schedutils
```

Then you can use `taskset` to change the affinity for a certain PID. Here's the man page: http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/taskset1.html

So you would ideally only dedicate 7 cores to Postgres, leaving 1 core for your system.

Comment: Taskset changes can also be added to the service startup script. I did the same for a MySQL instance.

Comment: You can also do it via systemd, e.g.: 'systemctl edit postgresql@12-main' with [Service] CPUAffinity=0-2 - there are NUMAPolicy and NUMAMask options as well for those with multi-processor systems, I recommend using NUMAPolicy=preferred or local, not bind, as the latter can cause out-of-memory errors and query termination under memory pressure.